# 2 decimal places on float using array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to display 5.00 using array...but when i do it only displays 5.0...here is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
<h1>Baltazar</h1>
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Baltazar</h1>
    <h3>Items: 15</h3>
    <% array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'Passed', 'Failed', 'Items', 'Score', 'Ratings', 'Grade', 'Remarks', 'Below', '.'] %>

    <%= array1[12]%> : <%= items = (array1[1].to_s + array1[5].to_s).to_i %><br>
    <%= array1[13] %> : <%= array1[0] %>-<%= array1[6] %><br>
    <%= array1[14] %> : <%= (array1[7].to_s + array1[1].to_s).to_i %> <%=  array1[17] %><br>
    <%= array1[15] %> : <%= (array1[5].to_s + array1[18].to_s + array1[0].to_s + array1[0].to_s).to_f %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? The way you've set your Array and how you get each element is not dynamic, and can be improved. We just need to know what you want to do so we can give you a nice Rails-way to do it ;-)

Comment: @MrYoshiji i want to display 5.00 at this part 

<%= array1[15] %> : <%= (array1[5].to_s + array1[18].to_s + array1[0].to_s + array1[0].to_s).to_f %> 

but it only displays 5.0...
i used float so that i can achieve it but it seems tough right there...how can i display 5.00? :)

Answer (score 2):

Function [number_to_currency](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) do it and somethings more

```
<%= number_to_currency(number, precision: 2, separator: ".", format: "%n") %>
```

Comment: im actually using an array...and im calling the value of an array...can you give me an example using an array?

Answer (score 1):

Use number_with_precision

```
<%= number_with_precision(number, precision: 2) %>
```

Comment: how can i put it in here <%= (array1[5].to_s + array1[18].to_s + array1[0].to_s + array1[0].to_s).to_f %> ? this is my only problem...